# multiple custom validators in reactive form angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have two custom `validator` in a `reactive form`, I call function below to create form in component constructor:

```
private createForm(): void {
this.passwordUpdateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    newpassword : [null, Validators.required],
    passwordconfirm: [null, Validators.required]
},
{
    validator: [PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch, PasswordValidation.PasswordRule] // validation method

});
```

}

**PasswordValidation** is a class with two functions like below

```
    export class PasswordValidation {

     public  static PasswordMatch(control: AbstractControl) {
        let password = control.get('newpassword'); // to get value in input tag
        if(password){
            let confirmPassword = control.get('passwordconfirm').value; // to get value in input tag
            if (password.value !== confirmPassword) {
                control.get('passwordconfirm').setErrors({ ['passwordmatch'] : true});
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static PasswordRule(control: AbstractControl) {
        let password = control.get('newpassword').value; // to get value in input tag
        let pattern = new RegExp('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,64}');               
        if (!pattern.test(password)) {
            control.get('newpassword').setErrors({ ['passwordrule'] : true});
        }else if (password.toLowerCase() === 'something') {
            control.get('newpassword').setErrors({ ['passwordrule'] : true});
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

each custom validator works fine separately like this

```
validator: PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch
```

or this

```
validator: PasswordValidation.PasswordRule
```

but using both of them in array like

```
validator: [PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch, PasswordValidation.PasswordRule]
```

get error `this.validator is not a function` and does not work, I do not have any idea, please help.

Comment: can you try with `Validators.compose() `which accepts multiple validators against one field.

Comment: Yes use compose(): validator: Validators.compose([[PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch, PasswordValidation.PasswordRule])}

Comment: @Vega does not work

Comment: You have the same error or it doesn't validate?

Comment: @Vega O It is working, thanks. your comment made me to check it again,I was so bored! thank you so much

Comment: Great! glad it worked :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

its better to use  `Validators.compose([])` which accepts the array of validators to be used on the specific user control in the form group.

for example if you want to add the validators against the  `passwordconfirm` and `newpassword` control you can do it like below

```
private createForm(): void {
this.passwordUpdateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    newpassword : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required,PasswordValidation.PasswordRule])],
    passwordconfirm: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, PasswordValidation.PasswordMatch])]
});
```

under the hood this is what the code looks like

```
group(controlsConfig: {[key: string]: any}, extra: {[key: string]: any} = null): FormGroup {
  const controls = this._reduceControls(controlsConfig);
  const validator: ValidatorFn = isPresent(extra) ? extra['validator'] : null;
  const asyncValidator: AsyncValidatorFn = isPresent(extra) ? extra['asyncValidator'] : null;
  return new FormGroup(controls, validator, asyncValidator);
}
```

you can see the paramater `validator` is actually a type of interface `ValidatorFn` which looks like below

```
interface ValidatorFn { 
  (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null
}
```

so you can see it can accept any method that has the above signature.

Source : https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn

Check this link for more : https://toddmotto.com/reactive-formgroup-validation-angular-2

Comment: I've tested it, but no success because `validators.compose` accepts validarots which returns `observable` or `promise` :/

Comment: @Parid0kht I think you are talking about async validators but from your code you are using only static sync validators. For sync validators Observable or Promise is not required. I have updated my answer with the explanation why you are not able to pass the validators as an array to the `formbuilder.group() ` method.